# c# additional input window on button click

Tags: c#, windows, forms, input

What is the best way to implement an additional input window that shows up if the user has another 'object' to input? I'm developing the form using visual studio c# windows form.

**Example**
consider the following data structure

`University->Departments -> courses`

The form has three group boxes. General university info on top with controls to input general university information.
Then departments group box with controls to input department information. I wold like to add `add dept` button/label below this group box to show the same controls to add another department's information. I would like to add courses the same way to each department with `add course` button.

**Additional info**

- The form handles one university at a time (no `add university` button)
- Each university have at least 1 department and each department has at least 1 course
- Maximum number of departments and max number of courses a dept can have is **known**. But putting all controls on the form will make the form really 'bulky'

Thanks for the help in advance. Pointers to any online resources is appreciated as well.

Comment: And what's the question? What have you tried? Where did you stumble? Anything?

Comment: Consider using WPF, as dynamically generating controls is very messy. WPF can do it for you with an `ItemTemplate`!

Comment: @Bradley: Great! Instead of one problem you now have two.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not saying its an *easy* switch, but that tech does handle this (and many other) use case far better than WinForms. Its unquestionably not an answer to this question, but simply a suggestion.

Comment: @Kennedy No problem. Once you get a bit of reputation (answer some questions, do some edits) swing by the WPF chatroom if you run into any problems that wouldn't make a good SO question.